# Error: You are using an unsupported version of Node

Tags: nodejs, laravel-8

Buenas tardes estoy instalando Laravel 8.0 y de momento bien, también he intalado `composer require laravel/breeze --dev` para soportar registro de usuarios. Normalmente utilizo Laravel 5.8.

Ha ido todo bien hasta que arranco la página y los CSS y JS me devuelven error 404! Por lo que veo ahora están en resources/css/app.css. Yo he seguido los procesos de la página oficial.

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev

php artisan breeze:install

npm install

npm run dev

php artisan migrate
```

**Por lo que he leido hay que hay que hacer esto:**

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Pero aquí me devuelve un error de Node:

> Error: You are using an unsupported version of Node. Please update to
> at least Node v12.14
> at assertSupportedNodeVersion (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Engine.js:6:15)
> at executeScript (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/laravel-mix/bin/cli.js:61:5)
> at Command.program.command.description.option.action.cmd (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/laravel-mix/bin/cli.js:47:13)
> at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/commander/index.js:426:31)
> at Command._parseCommand (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/commander/index.js:1002:14)
> at Command._dispatchSubcommand (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/commander/index.js:953:18)
> at Command._parseCommand (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/commander/index.js:979:12)
> at Command.parse (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/commander/index.js:801:10)
> at Command.parseAsync (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/commander/index.js:828:10)
> at run (/var/www/bartender/node_modules/laravel-mix/bin/cli.js:50:19)

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Tienes que actualizar la version de node porque `Laravel Breeze` utiliza `Tailwind` y este requiere version posterior a v12.13 de node para instalarse, esto lo dice la [documentacion](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v2)

Comment: El mismo mensaje de error da la solución, ¿ya lo intentaste?

Comment: No lo entiendo muy bien lo que pone, vi que parece que ponga como solucionarlo, pero esto es la primera vez que lo hago y me da cosa estropear algo del servidor

Comment: @Miguel te indica que debes actualizar tu nodejs a la versión 12.14 al menos

Comment: Tienes razón, perdón por la pregunta absurda, pero me veo desbocado con las cosas diferentes de Laravel 8, voy a ver como actualizarlo. Veo que tengo las verisón 10.19.0 de node

Comment: Reafirmando lo que dice @JuanRivera aqui [puedes leer los requisitos de Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Comment: Ok, me pongo a ello de como actualizar node, que es la primera vez que lo hago, gracias chicos!

Comment: Creare una respuesta porque no veo hay una pregunta asi en el sitio

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar, pero publicala tu mismo ya que me habeis dado la solución. La verdad me gustaria aprender algo más de esto, por que utilizar Laravel Mix y lo compila, la verdad que no lo entiendo mucho jeje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas tratando de instalar *Tailwind CSS* haciendo: `npm install` ya que [*Laravel Breeze*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) lo tiene incluido por defecto. Pero para poder instalarlo se requiere una version de Node superior a `12.13.0` como dice la [documentacion](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#installing-tailwind-css-as-a-post-css-plugin) (traducido a español):

> Tailwind CSS requiere Node.js 12.13.0 o superior.

Por lo que la solucion es simple, actualiza la version de tu node y listo!